# Homophone Riddle 9

Tags: riddle, word

A good description: A word you know, a homophone you don't

```
I could be a fruit you never have heard of,
Or what Darth Vader is under his mask
It is a cross between two fruits you know,
Or what everyone thinks mold is
```

I made this riddle because of my 1000 reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> ugly

I could be a fruit you never have heard of,

> [Ugli fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugli_fruit)

Or what Darth Vader is under his mask

> one ugly m--f--

It is a cross between two fruits you know

> "a citrus fruit created by hybridizing a grapefruit (or pomelo), an orange and a tangerine."

Or what everyone thinks mold is

> o gross

Comment: Beat me to it with 17 seconds haha. Although I don't know if it holds up the your 3rd hint's answer (same problem I was having).

Comment: yeah .. not sure there, but there might be a 'cross of a cross'.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is right, but I'll still throw it out there for now:

> Ugli fruit

I could be a fruit you never have heard of

> I hadn't, but that's just me.

Or what Darth Vader is under his mask

> I don't actually know what you're looking for here, but some people may consider his burnt face to be ugly I guess.

It is a cross between two fruits you know

> I think the Ugli is a cross of three fruits though, so doesn't really hold up here? The taste is likened to just two fruits though, lemon and something else.

Or what everyone thinks mold is

> Yeah, I dunno. Ugly or gross?

A good description: A word you know, a homophone you don't

> Ugly is known, Ugli is not

I made this riddle because of my 1000 reputation.

> Congrats. Not sure if this is also a hint or not though.

Comment: great minds think alike